# Where do I get historic performance data of the MSCI World Growth/Value index

Tags: historical-data, index

I'm looking for a free data source of historical performance data of the MSCI world Value- and Growth index. The data should be calculated with reinvested dividends.

Comment: Which MSCI world Value- and Growth index? For Which Country?

Comment: For the whole World in USD

Comment: Welcome to Quantitative Finance ! please add more details by editing your question.

Comment: I am also looking for that information. The data on the MSCI webpage goes only back until 2002 or so but the index started much earlier (1969 according to wikipedia). I found historical returns on a bunch of sites but they all go back only a few years. Does anyone know how to access the full history?

Comment: Actually, I now found it here: http://www.msci.com/eqb/esg/performance/106.0.all.xls

Comment: @thias How did you find this link? Are there also such links for other MSCI indexes?

Comment: Replace `106` in that URL with the desired `indexId`, which can be found in the `End of day index data search` section: Copy the link of the index that appears in the search results, then look for the number that follows `indexId=`. For example, EAFE is `108`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is available directly from MSCI's website: [MSCI End of Day Index Data Search](https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-search). If you click on an index name, you can download the entire history.

Comment: It seems to require Adobe Flash. Who still has flash these days :( Are you still able to download the data?

Comment: @BaptisteWicht as of 2023, that link doesn't require flash, anymore. That means I can navigate it and download historic index data via Firefox. However, with Firefox I have to use a private window since perhaps the page isn't compatible with my ad blocker (uBlock Origin). Also, surprisingly, the site doesn't work with Chromium, for me. That means when I select 'reject all' (unnecessary) cookies there, the main page view is empty. If I allow all cookies I get an index list but when I select a certain index the load-screen never goes away. In a private window, where addons are disabled that is.

Comment: @maxschlepzig Thanks, I can see the data now!