# Download historical MSCI/GICS Sector Index data

Tags: data, market-data, historical-data, indexes

Similar to [Where do I get historic performance data of the MSCI World Growth/Value index](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/28292/where-do-i-get-historic-performance-data-of-the-msci-world-growth-value-index), I'm looking for historical data for the MSCI Sector Indexes (Energy, Material, Industrials, Financials and so on).

The linked tool at https://www.msci.com/end-of-day-data-search unfortunately doesn't contain any historical data for the Sector Indexes.

Comment: You could use the usual Market data providers or, from what I see under the link you've provided use the information there. I see a field named "as of" giving you the data for the specified day. You could iterate through with a script and save the data you need quote easily since everything is presented in a table format already and it's possible to filter for what you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, the "Sector" tab of the End-of-day search doesn't support any other day than the last trading day. Which market data providers offer index data? I only found stock or ETF data.